# HTML videos preloading

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

We are developing Interactive 2d games, we use the HTML5 videos to show segments with heavy animations,as you may know we are using a lot of resources like images, svgs , since these resources are preloaded once you open the game so they are working great.

but we noticed that when we try to open a video it take a time to play until it is loaded.

Is their a way to preload a 10 videos (for example) once the user opens our website?

Answer (score -1):

There are many libraries that help to prevent those long loadings on videos or audio in html.
Personally my favourite is Media Element.js
http://mediaelementjs.com/
To install, follow the instructions on the website and on the document README.